# nested_form_fields gem, options_for_select with jQuery chaining not working rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am using the nested_form_fields gem - with chained options_for_select.  The 'selected option' isn't saving.  The chaining, itself, is working.  The gem is written in javascript, so there may be a basic conflict between the gem and jQuery chaining.  Hopefully, though, I'm overlooking something else.

Model - user.rb:

```
has_many :state_registrations, inverse_of: :user,
  dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :state_registrations
```

Model - state_registrations.rb:

```
belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :state_registrations
```

View - users/_form.html.erb:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 form-group">
  <%= f.nested_fields_for :state_registrations, :html => { :multipart => true },
  wrapper_tag: :div do |state_registration_fields| %>
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <%= state_registration_fields.label :state_license, "State" %>
      <%= state_registration_fields.select :state_license,
      options_for_select(@state_licenses_1), {}, {class: 
      "state_license form-control btn-default btn-block", 
      name: "state_license"} %>
    </div>
....
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
  <%= state_registration_fields.label :state_license_number, 
  "License Number or 'Exempt' " %>
  <%= state_registration_fields.text_field :state_license_number, 
  class: "form-control input", type: "text", placeholder: "License 
  Number"  %>
</div>
....
```

Javascript - custon.js:
This follows the excellent work of Mika Tuupola [Chained selects plugin for jQuery and Zepto](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained), remote verson.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".state_license_name_user").remoteChained({
    parents : ".state_license",
    url : "state_registrations/state_license_name_user",
    loading : "Loading...",
    clear : true
  });
});
```

Controller - state_registrations_controller.rb:
This is what's chained:

```
def state_license
  @state_licenses = ['State (select)'] + StateRegistration.all.order(:state_license).pluck(:state_license).uniq
end

def state_license_name_user
  state_license_name_users = StateRegistration
     .where("state_license = ?", params[:state_license])
     .order(:state_license_name_user)
     .pluck(:state_license_name_user).uniq
  render :json => state_license_name_users.map {|value| [value, value]}
end
```

Controller - users_controller.rb:

```
def update
    @user = User.includes(:state_registrations).find(params[:id])
raise params.inspect
```

The params returned show that the :state_license_number - which isn't chained - is part of the state_registrations hash.  The chained options_for_select, :state_license and :state_license_name_user (not shown in above view), are separate (at the end):

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxx==", 
"user"=>{"email"=>"xxx", ..., "state_registrations_attributes"=>{"0"=  
{"state_license_number"=>"OREGON-12345", "submitted_by"=>"user"}}, ..., 
"state_license"=>"Oregon", "state_license_name_user"=>"Tax Preparer", 
"commit"=>"UPDATE Profile", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"update", 
"id"=>"1"}
```

The three fields, :state_license, :state_license_name_user, and :state_license_number, are part of the state_registrations table.  They aren't separately included in the users table.  The state_registration and user models are indexed, i.e., the state_registrations table has a user_id field and the users table has a state_registration_id field.

I tried several work-arounds with no success at saving :state_license and :state_license_name_user including using collection_select, using the child index of each record to namespace (although, candidly, I'm not sure I was doing it correctly).  I think I need to get this saving before worrying about the chaining.  (1) Chaining works when there's only one record.  (2) It breaks with multiple records.

The nested_form_fields gem does provide for 'Namespaced Associations'; however, I don't understand the suggested usage [which, nevertheless, I tried, following the example shown - again without success] and / or if its applicable here.  [Nested_Form_Fields documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nested_form_fields/0.7.5)

Because the gem is written in javascript, using options_for_select with jQuery chaining may not be feasible without a re-write of the gem's code.  However, I'd like to get some feedback.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at your view it seems state_license_number is not nested inside f.nested_fields_for :state_registrations. But it needs to be if its a field of state_registrations. And yes, you should first make this work without the jquery addon. You don't use a namespaced association so you can ignore that part of the docs.

Comment: @nico Nico, thank you for responding.  Justin Love and I resolved earlier this afternoon - and will post an answer later.  The issue had nothing to do with your gem and / or a conflict with options for select jquery chaining.  Rather, I need to establish a has many through association for state registrations.  I was inadvertently trying to save to a master table.

Comment: Ah, great to hear you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

The extra gems and plugins obscure the real issue, which is in the schema design. `state_registrations` is acting as both a master table (which would define the available options in the select) and had a `user_id` field - the design would not work for more than one user with a given license type. It really needs a join table between registrations and users to express the many-many relationship.

Rails supports simple many-many relations with [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association), although I usually prefer an explicit join table with [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), because it allows attaching additional information. Example: date the license was obtained, or next expiration.

[Choosing Between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Disclaimer: I met the user IRL and spent some time discussing the schema and intent to understand what was going on.